# Jquery UI: autocomplete search by multi data column from mysql db

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am now trying to do a dynamic autocomplete search from db.
What I want is when I insert 'P1', my autocomplete will display 'P1623AD' & 'P123AD'

 or when I insert 'hard' then autocomplete show 'hardware'.
Current I can only search by 1 column.
[image]

My query:

```
$ItemDetail = array();

$getItemSQL = base_executeSQL("SELECT eitem_item_code,eitem_item_name FROM eitem_item");

while($Item_row = base_fetch_array($getItemSQL)){
    $ItemDetail[]=$Item_row;
}  

echo json_encode($ItemDetail);
```

My Jquery:

```
$('input#item_search').autocomplete({
    source:function (request,response){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            data:{term:request.term},
            dataType:'json',
            url:'search_item.php',
            success:function(data){

            response($.map(data, function (item)
            {
                // return 
                //alert(data[0]);
                return{item.eitem_item_code,item.eitem_item_name
                }; 
            }));
            }
        });
    },
    minLength:1
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late reply, But it's worth of knowing it. Your query should have `LIKE` condition with multiple fields I mean what are the fields you want to search with.

```
$getItemSQL = base_executeSQL("SELECT eitem_item_code,eitem_item_name FROM eitem_item WHERE eitem_item_code LIKE '{$_GET['term']}' OR ANOTHER_FIELD_FROM_TABLE LIKE '{$_GET['term']}'");
```